# limit value taxonomy based on previous taxonomy value wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have created a custom Post Type which Holds up-to Two Taxonomies called "country"- values: "USA", "Russia", "China" , "city" - values: "Chicago", "Moscow", "Beijing",

I want when user in taxonomy "country" choose value "USA" after that in taxonomy  "city" show only "chicago". Is it possible? And how can I do this?

is there wordpress plugin that does this?